# MySQL Finding the End Position of String within String

Tags: mysql, string

I'm looking for a way to identify the end position of a matched string within a string. If I have the following text in a field:

```
The book is on the shelf
```

And I want to find the ending position of the text "on", I can find the start using locate(), which returns the starting position, but I'm trying to get the ending position as well.

My expected result then would be something like this:

```
Text                     | End Position
----------------------------------------------
The book is on the shelf | 14
```

I have a query that uses a LIKE to find matching text with wildcards.  I'm searching across a field that can contain 5000 characters of text, and of course trying to find the matching text in this field is time consuming.  Therefore, I was hoping there is a way to basically show where the LIKE has matched the text. Maybe both the start and ending positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT @a := 'The book is on the shelf', 
    LOCATE('on', @a) AS pos_initial, 
    (LOCATE('on', @a) + LENGTH('on')) as pos_final;
```